# Pass arguments to DockerFile from docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Sorry if this is duplicate but after going through several question I still couldn't fix how to provide value to DockerFile at runtime.
Both DockerFile and docker-compose are at same directory structure.
This is my DockerFile -

```
#Pulling base image with python. The OS is Debian.
FROM python:3.9-buster

ARG secret="abc"
RUN echo "some variable ${secret} ."
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/ece-prm-agent

# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /tmp/ece-prm-agent

RUN cd /tmp/ece-prm-agent && git clone https://usrn:${secret}A@github.optum.com/ElasticSearch/ece-prm.git
```

and this is my docker compose YAML file -

```
version: "3.4"
services:
   python-agent:
       build:
         context: .
       container_name: mrp
       working_dir: /code
```

And this is my command that I'm executing -
`docker-compose build --build-arg secret=xyz`

The output is not throwing any error but it is not picking up the value I provided at GitHub clone time. I want to clone GitHub with credentials provided at runtime-

```
Building python-agent
Step 1/5 : FROM python:3.9-buster
 ---> da24d18bf4bf
Step 2/5 : ARG secret="abc"
 ---> Running in 17502deddb5d
Removing intermediate container 17502deddb5d
 ---> b939fef27718
Step 3/5 : RUN echo "some variable ${secret} ."
 ---> Running in 4bc966e157fc
some variable xyz .
Removing intermediate container 4bc966e157fc
 ---> 159e9020e914
Step 4/5 : RUN mkdir -p /tmp/ece-prm-agent
 ---> Running in a3b9c5bded8a
Removing intermediate container a3b9c5bded8a
 ---> 5028916a8c0e
Step 5/5 : WORKDIR /tmp/ece-prm-agent
 ---> Running in c7b69ad61a7e
Removing intermediate container c7b69ad61a7e
 ---> 5ee70e5e4e91

Successfully built 5ee70e5e4e91
```

Comment: Remember that anyone who gets this image can run `docker history` and see the `secret`.  I'd suggest running the `git` operation on the host, outside of Docker, and avoid needing this credential at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze how can he view docker history?

Comment: Run `docker history 5ee70e5e4e91` (or whatever the image name/ID is) and it will show you the sequence of commands used to build the image.  If you push the image to Docker Hub, it has a similar listing.

Comment: @DavidMaze Ohhh! So would you suggest to use COPY  ./src instead?

Comment: Yes.  That will also get you around a couple of practical issues with running `git` in Docker (you can only build committed versions and not a local test tree; layer caching means the repository won't get pulled again even if there are changes upstream).

Comment: @DavidMaze But you can't provide a path right? It has to be in the same directory with DockerFile.

Comment: @DavidMaze Nevermind! I got it. Thank you that was quite insight full.

Comment: There are a couple of ways of solving the build secret problem. One is to ensure its stored in a tmpfs layer.
Another, perhaps less technical, is to throw away they entire builder container. by doing a multistage build.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
args:                                                                     
         - secret=my_secret
```

to your docker-compose under build and put argument between "" in the docker-compose build command.